# OneSignal Push Notification Link Back to App

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, mobile, onesignal

I am building a mobile application using Ionic, and decided to use OneSignal for push notifications. I need to have a user be able to click a push notification (text message) and have the app load to a specific page in the app. I was reading information on deep linking, but it's unclear if it applies to what I'm trying to do. I don't want to load anything in a browser.

For example, I may send a text message that says "A new message is available!" If a user clicks the notification, I want to open the application, and go directly to the specific message.

Does someone have an example or can point to the correct documentation?

Answer (score 1):

i have some views about fcm with ionic 3, hope this will help you

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
        if(data.wasTapped){
           if(data.location == "StoriesPage"){
             this.loading = this.loadCtrl.create({
               content:'Loading Stories....',
               duration:2000
             })
             this.loading.present();
             this.rootPage = HomePage;
       
           } else if(data.location == 'HomePage'){
             this.rootPage = HomePage;
           } else if(data.location == 'SubscriptionPage'){
             this.rootPage = SubscriptionPage;
           }
         }
          console.log("Received in background");
        } else {
          console.log("Received in foreground");
        };
      });
```

here i sent a location attribute as payload of notification data..if based on that i added rootpage

try to approach the same as per your requirement

Comment: This is really helpful. What do you put in the text message that will open the app and contain the payload? That's the side I don't understand as well - the backend service.

Comment: 1.opening will be taken care by notification click it self
2.sending data you need to handle in push notification message dashboard